# Website is Indexed but not listed for keywords in google

Tags: seo

I am doing seo for my website, I am facing a strange problem while i optimize my website.

My site is indexed in google but not showing for my keyword. I searched first 100 pages in google,but my website is not appearing for the keyword.Google is not considering my company has a webdesigning company. Not only this keyword. i can't get my website in google search result for any keyword.

The keyword i am targeting is “web designing company in MY CITY”
I will list out all the things i have done so far.

- The key word is present in  tag.
- Keyword is present in meta keyword and meta description.
- Keyword is also present in the home page for 4 times.
- Added my site in webmaster tools.
- Site map Submitted and No crawl errors.
- Added my website in google analytics.
- Created a G+ page and its verified.
- keyword is present in G+ page description.
- 5 reviews in G+ page. All are 5 Star Reviews.
- Added my address in Structured data in webmaster tools.
- I believe that my site is providing relevant content to users
  regarding web design services.
- Added G+ badge to website.
- According to MOZ open Site explorer. 9 Domains Pointing to my
  website, 84 links have my website in their page.
- Domain authority is 16 and Page Authority is 29.
- Marked has a local business
- Google map has my Location.

Recently i posted a new blog in my website.Google showed the blog in first page for few hours but now its not showing the result. I searched this again in first 100 pages.

Overall Google is not recognizing my company has a Web Designing company. If i search web designing company i can see all other companies listed but not mine.

I get lots of spam traffic in google analytic.

My domain ranking is varying in many places. 
Moz Open site explorer - Domain Authority 16
Ahrefs Site Explorer - Domain Authority 48

I don't know why this is happening. Did i missed anything? Can anyone please help me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: A lot of what you listed does not affect your rankings. Even then, there's no way for us to know why Google does not rank your site as well as you think it should.

Comment: I count only 3-4 things in your list that will do anything for you and it is standard minimal stuff- not enough to even get started. All the G+, MOZ, linking Google products, sitemap, etc. does absolutely nothing. Please keep in mind that most all of all the SEO advice on the web is self-serving and absolute bull squirt. Pay attention to on-page optimization and links first, schema.org mark-up second, and making sure you are natural and not trying to move search engines through your superior usage of keywords. They are far smarter than this. Create fantastic content first, SEO last.